# Angular click events not working on expanded columns in jquery responsive datatable

Tags: jquery, angular, datatables, stackblitz

I'm using jquery responsive datatable with my angular 6 application. 
I want to put two button at the last td in each row. But none of the events are working on the collapsed tds.

After setting below property on the datatable, events are working but after each event, buttons are repeated. At first I have 2 buttons, after clicking on the button and completing the operation, i get 4 buttons, and buttons keeps on increasing.

```
Datatable configuration:
const table: any = $('#contract-table');
        table.DataTable().destroy();
        this.dataTable = table.DataTable({
          responsive: {
            details: {
                renderer: Responsive.renderer.listHiddenNodes()
            }
          }
        });

Angular code: 

<table class="table table-hover dt-responsive nowrap" id="contract-table" cellspacing="0">
              <thead class="thead-dark">
                  <tr>
                      <th>Contract Number</th>
                      <th>Contract Title</th>
                      <th>Contract Type</th>
                      <th>DUNS</th>
                      <th>Cage Code</th>
                      <th>DoDAAC</th>
                      <th>DCMA Administered</th>
                      <th>Category</th>
                      <th>Customer/Agency</th>
                      <th>Customer/Agency Other</th>
                      <th>Contract Clauses</th>
                      <th>PWS/SOW Authroization Data</th>
                      <th>Contract Dollar Value</th>
                      <th>Contract Classification</th>
                      <th>Indefinite Delivery Contract</th>
                      <th>Indefinite Delivery Type</th>
                      <th>Contract Description</th>
                      <th></th>
                  </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                  <tr *ngFor="let contract of contracts" (click)="selectedContract = selectedContract && selectedContract.id === contract.id ? null : contract" [ngClass]="{'selected-contract': selectedContract && selectedContract.id === contract.id}">
                      <td>{{contract?.contractNumber}}</td>
                      <td>{{contract?.title}}</td>
                      <td>{{contract?.contractType}}</td>
                      <td>{{contract?.duns}}</td>
                      <td>{{contract?.cageCode}}</td>
                      <td>{{contract?.doDAAC}}</td>
                      <td>{{contract?.dcmaAdministered ? 'Yes' : 'No'}}</td>
                      <td>{{contract?.category}}</td>
                      <td>{{contract?.customerAgency}}</td>
                      <td>{{contract?.customerAgencyOther}}</td>
                      <td>{{contract?.contractClauses}}</td>
                      <td>{{contract?.authorizationData}}</td>
                      <td>{{contract?.contractDollarValue}}</td>
                      <td>{{contract?.contractClassification}}</td>
                      <td>{{contract?.indefiniteDeliveryContract ? 'Yes' : 'No'}}</td>
                      <td>{{contract?.indefiniteDeliveryType}}</td>
                      <td>{{contract?.contractDescription}}</td>
                      <td>
                        <div class="row pull-right">
                            <div class="col pr-0">
                                <button mat-button class="btn btn-custom btn-bordred btn-block" (click)="onCreateSubContract('edit', contract)">Edit</button>
                            </div>
                           <div class="col">
                              <button mat-button class="btn btn-custom btn-bordred btn-block btn-create-sub-contract" (click)="onCreateSubContract('sub', contract)">Create Subcontract</button>
                           </div>
                        </div>
                      </td>
                  </tr>
              </tbody>
</table>
```

angular click events should work fine.

Comment: Please share any working fiddle for more clarification. Thanks

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bv9bdw
Here is the fiddle. But this is not working fine. Jquery datatables are not loading there. Please help with that as well. If datatables are loaded fine, button events will stop. Since datatables are not working now, button events are working

Answer (score 0):

Just change your `(click)="selectedContract = selectedContract && selectedContract.id === contract.id ? null : contract"` to `(click)="selectedContractMethod()"` and move your code to **separate method** in **ts** file.

```
selectedContractMethod() {
  // Paste your code here
}
```

I hope it'll resolve your issue. Thanks

Comment: that is working fine already. 
buttons in the td are not working when the responsive columns are in expanded form. onCreateSubContract() is not working

Comment: Both `Edit` and `Create Subcontract` **(click)** working fine, they also print **event** string in console. Please review it. Thanks

Comment: that is because datatable is not loaded properly and columns are expanding and collapsing. issue persists only when the columns are in expanded form.
In console there is an error "ERROR
Error: table.DataTable is not a function"

Comment: Can you share the link where your datatable, expanding and collapsing working properly? Thanks